# Where did my comment go?

Tags: support, migration

I go to stackoverflow and find I have two responses to a comment--but when I try to load the thread neither my comment nor any responses to it seem to be there.

It looks like something went wrong with a migration.

[Solving maze without return ability](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15554/solving-maze-without-return-ability)

Comment: It's entirely possible that your comment was deleted.

Comment: @ChrisF:  But there are no replies, either--that would mean that both of the replies would also have to have been deleted.

Comment: @ChrisF I removed comments prior to migration. I figured migrating 21 comments was a bit much. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looked like the relevant information was edited into the question, so I removed comments on the question prior to migration.

The relevant responses are below.

> This makes no sense. If you know the room ID and the numbers on the doors you have all the information you need in order to backtrack. Thus how can you say no backtracking unless the robot has no memory--but in that case you can't apply any intelligence to it anyway--simply choose a random door. --Loren Pechtel
>
> @Loren, initially robot doesn't know where is he. Only ID of current room and IDs of doors from it. While it moves from room to room he of course can store to memory visited rooms. The only problem is that he doesn't know where he came from (what door ID of new room leads back to previous room) when enter new room. --archer
>
> @Loren The door IDs are not the same as the room IDs, right archer? --Byte56
>
> Yes. For example, we have rooms 1, 2, 3. Inside room 1 we have doors A, B. Inside room 2: A, B, C... etc. --archer

Comment: Except I was addressing the current version of the question that says "We know exactly ID of current room. We know ID of each door in current room (not in all maze)."  From those comments you zapped it appears this is poorly stated.