# Where my comment gone and what was the reason to removal?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment regarding accept rate removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110644/comment-regarding-accept-rate-removed)

I had commented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168891/sms-message-composer-xcode-iphone-customization-image-attachment-mfmessagecompo) on stackoverflow.com and got reply before 1 hour. It sounds weird but my comment has gone!?

How do I know what was my comment, or what was the reason for removal of comment?

I have checked similar [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100924/where-did-my-comment-go) but it is something different against my case as it is something about migration which is not the case in my case.

Comment: Judging by the OPs reply, you nagged about accept rate. It got flagged and automatically removed.

Comment: Whoops! I flagged the OP's reply as "obsolete" and it was insta-deleted as well. No biggie; simchona is correct. You nagged them about their accept rate, and they commented (basically) that they don't care about accept rate and that you should answer the question. Nagging people about their accept rate is not considered appropriate, and people like me flag those routinely, causing them to be removed.

Comment: So you mean to say encourage or telling to accept answers which helped them is something unethical on stackoverflow ? I have seen lots of comments like those and It was not with negative intention to post comment. What do you say on that ?

Comment: See the answers to the linked questions in the first comment. But the short answer is that yes, nagging people about their accept rate is unwelcome.

Comment: @TheEstablishment thax I got My answer. You flagged and was removed. can u please post it so that I will accept it and considered this question as closed. Thax once again.

Comment: @TheEstablishment as per my knowledge questions u asked and mark as accepted if you are satisfied are considered in accept rate. so let say that buddy had 5 questions and accepted only 1 answer so his accept rate is 20%. This is what I see. If its different I would like to know abt that.

Comment: Consider comments as something only temporary and insignificant - this will help you avoid grief when they are deleted. :)